# Saving video to android device (unity)

Tags: unity, android, client-server

How can I create a folder on Android device, download from ftp-server video and save it there?

Answer (score 1):

You can create directory in andriod

**using System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path)**

```
string path = "/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder";

 if(!Directory.Exists(path))
      Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

and you can download any resource form the web using [**WWW**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html).

Comment: Will it work on Android?

Comment: yes try it first separately and let me know.

Comment: Would this be a case where you want to use Application.persistentDataPath to help keep your app's saved files organized in a consistent spot?

Comment: @DMGregory Sorry https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html is much better choice.